# How to make my text \raggedleft correctly?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I create a new command `byorfrom` with `\newcommand{\byorfrom}[1]{\newline\raggedleft\notefontitalic<\,#1\,>}`, I want to make the text output from the next line at right side. Something as:
[image]

But the result from:

```
The first paragraph.

The second paragraph. \byorfrom{chapter-1}
```

is
[image]

The second paragraph isn't in its right place which I mean, starts from left as the first paragraph before it.
If I add one more pair of braces to the command definition, `\newcommand{\byorfrom}[1]{{\newline\raggedleft\notefontitalic<\,#1\,>}}`, then the example will be:

[image]
Now the text `<chapter-1>` is wrong position. And if I make that pair of braces after `\newline` as `\newcommand{\byorfrom}[1]{\newline{\raggedleft\notefontitalic<\,#1\,>}}` , same result:

[image]

How do I make the command work as I wish?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
\def\byorfrom #1{\par {\leftskip=0pt plus1fill\relax #1\par}}

The first paragraph.

The second paragraph. \byorfrom{chapter-1}
```

The setting `\leftskip=0pt plus1fill\relax` is equivalent to the `\raggedleft`.

Your problem is that the `\raggedleft` setting sets `\leftskip` and its value us used at the `\par` processing. So, you must process `\par` before leaving of the group. Your second problem is, that you divide previous normal paragraph from the next "raggedlefted" by `\newline`, i.e. by `\hfil\break`, but it doesn't finalize the previous paragraph. If you want different formatting for the next paragraph, you must to end the previous one by `\par`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `\newline` approach is that in a paragraph you cannot have different directives, so `\raggedleft` wins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\byorfrom}[1]{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  {\raggedleft\notefontitalic\textup{\textlangle}#1\/\textup{\textrangle}\par}%
}
\newcommand\notefontitalic{\small\itshape}

\begin{document}

First paragraph

Second paragraph\byorfrom{Chapter 1}

\end{document}
```

[image]